# Manipulation check included in the correlation matrix?

Tags: correlation, matrix

For my master thesis, I'm doing an experiment in which I give participants the prospect of having AI implemented at the workspace. I've got 3 groups (Low prospect, high prospect and control) I have a manipulation check, with which I ask in the end of the survey to what extent participants feel AI will be implemented at their workspace before debriefing them.

I'm making a correlation matrix including all my relevant variables. I was wondering whether I should include my manipulation check (a continious variable) in my correlation matrix. It would already show the direction of my relatioinship.

Furthermore, can I use the manipulation check as a continious variable for prospect of AI implementation? That would make analysis a lot easier (Process all the way ;))